# jinja2 ignoring last new line?

Tags: python-2.7, templates, jinja2

I'm creating script that generates specific files using jinja2 as template engine. It creates file I expect, except for the last line. In template I have specified last empty line, but when file is created it does not have that line.

Template looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import fields, models, api


class {{ class_name }}(models.{{ model_type }}):
    """{{ class_docstring }}"""

    _{{ def_type }} = '{{ model }}'
# Here is actually empty line. Note comment does not exist on template. It is just empty line.
```

So in total there are 10 lines defined in this template. But file that is created using this template will only have 9 lines (that last line will not be created).

Is this expected behavior or it should create me that last line as I am expecting?

Here data and methods that handle rendering:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment(
    autoescape=True,
    loader=FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(PATH, 'templates')),
    trim_blocks=False)
...
...
    @staticmethod
    def render_template(t, context):
        # For now it only supports standard templates.
        template_filename = TEMPLATE_FILES_MAPPING[t]
        return TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template_filename).render(
            context)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`keep_trailing_newline`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) option may be what you're looking for:

> By default, Jinja2 also removes trailing newlines. To keep single
> trailing newlines, configure Jinja to keep_trailing_newline.

You can add it to the environment:

```
TEMPLATE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment(
    ...
    keep_trailing_newline=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to finish the template with two newlines and let jinja2 strip one of them:

```
File contents
File contents
...
       # Actual empty line (without this comment) which is kept by jinja2
       # Actual empty line (without this comment) which is stripped by jinja2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).